# Why is the result different from what I expect?

Tags: javascript

```js
emptyWord = '';

if (emptyWord !== false) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

If emptyWord is false, I want the `else` to run. If emptyWord is true, I want the `console.log(1)` to run.

I actually expected `console.log(2)` to run. Because `emptyWord` is a falsey value. The condition says, 'is a falsey value, not the same as false'. The answer to that is 'no/false'.

I know a better thing to put would've been: `emptyWord === true`.

But whilst we're here, how do you explain in words what's going on with the condition in the snippet. I think I read somewhere that you should try to avoid 'double-negatives'.

Comment: But `emptyWord ` is different from `false`!

Comment: `emptyWord` is a string. it is neither `true` nor `false`.

Comment: Doh! I see my error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `!== false` and not `!= false`.  When you use `!==` it isn't checking for "falsy", it's checking if it is actually `false` or not.

```js
console.log('' != false);
console.log('' !== false);
```

Answer (score 0):

it will always return true, because :
emptyword is not STRICTLY equals (=== means strictly equals) to false!

what you're probably looking for is !=, in this case it will convert the value 0 to false, for example. To note here, there is a difference between strictly equals and just plain equals (=== vs ==).

in english:

is emptyword not equal to false? in this case it is true, so it enters the first clause:
console.log(1);

take a look here for more examples :
https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 0):

You should use **!=false** because **!==false**  is strictly looking for not false

```
emptyWord = '';

if (emptyWord != false) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The !== operator checks if the **type** and the **value** of the variables are the same.
The != operator checks if only the value is the same.

'' and false are equals the same in terms of value in js, but '' is a string and false is a boolean value.

If you want to get **2** as return, you need to change your code to:

```
emptyWord = '';

if (emptyWord != false) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

('' !== false) is true.
('' != false) is false.